# psycopg2 for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, psycopg2

I am trying to run a jenkins job which runs on Python 2.7. The job clones a git repository in the Worspace. The repository has the 'site-packages' folder which contains the required packages. However, when trying to import psycopg2, I am getting the below error:

```
    import psycopg2
  File "/U01/jenkins/workspace/Certinal-Dashboard@script/3fd472cfae7a05e124db2e1ea25b136ecb9661026cf719c0011581747a11dea0/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
  File "/U01/jenkins/workspace/Certinal-Dashboard@script/3fd472cfae7a05e124db2e1ea25b136ecb9661026cf719c0011581747a11dea0/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/U01/jenkins/workspace/Certinal-Dashboard@script/3fd472cfae7a05e124db2e1ea25b136ecb9661026cf719c0011581747a11dea0/site-packages/psycopg2/extensions.py", line 37, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                             # noqa
  File "/U01/jenkins/workspace/Certinal-Dashboard@script/3fd472cfae7a05e124db2e1ea25b136ecb9661026cf719c0011581747a11dea0/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg/AsIs.py", line 9, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extensions'
```

I have installed psycopg2 version 2.7.5. The folders that are installed when I downloaded psycopg2 are:

**-psycopg2**
**-psycopg2-2.7.5.dist-info**

I have tried installing different versions of psycopg2 (i.e - ver-2.8, 2.7.7). I have also tried re-installing psycopg2 ver-2.7.5 in case the original package didn't download correctly.

Comment: Psycopg2 is a compiled C extension. It may not work if it is compiled on one machine and then the files are transferred to another.

Answer (score -1):

Please try installing and using [psycopg2-binary](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) package.

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
import psycopg2
```

Comment: There is no Python 2.7 wheel for psycopg2-binary.